# CareKit - Update activity status from start to end date in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, carekit

There is problem with update `OCKCarePlanEvent` status as completed  in `OCKCarePlanStore` from it's start to end date of an activity(`OCKCarePlanActivity`)

Explanation:

I have JSON from which i want to update events of activity from it's start to end date, but  OCKCareSchedule is only allow to schedule event     *weeklySchedule and dailySchedule.* Sample of JSON i used from date wise occurrence schedule for an activity with it's schedule(**PROBLEM: which only allow 7 dates occurrence of occurrences in OCKCareSchedule**)

```
 "occurrence": {
      "Sun, 19 Nov 2017" : [0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
      "Mon, 20 Nov 2017" : [0,1,0,1,1,0,0],
      "Tue, 21 Nov 2017" : [0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
      "Wed, 22 Nov 2017" : [0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      "Thu, 23 Nov 2017" : [0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
       "Fri, 24 Nov 2017" : [0,0,0],
      "Sat, 25 Nov 2017" : [0,0,0,0,1,0,0]
    },
```

Here array of 0 and 1 shows status of each events for that date (0: not completed, 1: completed)

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: if not understand i can explain stuff